# unable to start rstudio in centos getting error "unable to connect to service"

Tags: linux, r, centos, rstudio, rstudio-server

I have Rstudio server installed on CentOS 6, but I cannot login to Rstudio from the browser at http://localhost:8787 in browser. A popup titled "RStudio Initialization Error" appears with message "Unable to connect to service".

I have tried the following to remedy the error, but I have been without success:

```
$ sudo rstudio-server verify-installation
rstudio-server stop/waiting
rserver[19273]: ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied) [username=rstudio-server]; OCCURRED AT: core::Error server::launchSession(const std::string&, const core::system::Options&, PidType*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerSessionManager.cpp:223; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerMain.cpp:428
rstudio-server start/running, process 19287

$ id -u supstat1
502 (user name is more than 500)

$ sudo usermod -g rstudio_users supstat1

$ sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables as root
and added the following line(s)
Add -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8787 -j ACCEPT
Add -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

$ sudo lsof | grep rstudio
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  cwd       DIR                8,1      4096          2 /
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  rtd       DIR                8,1      4096          2 /
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  txt       REG                8,1   7990044     553699 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    156928     391944 /lib64/ld-2.12.so
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1   1926800     391948 /lib64/libc-2.12.so
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    599384     396110 /lib64/libm-2.12.so
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1     22536     391993 /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    145896     391952 /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1     91096     391950 /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1   1410824     564111 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    327488     567429 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    124624     396127 /lib64/libselinux.so.1
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    113952     406171 /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1     18936     396128 /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1     93320     396113 /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1     17256     392157 /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    177520     392161 /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1     12592     406310 /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.3
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    280520     392159 /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    944712     391997 /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1    989840     536152 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1     46368     406311 /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1     17520     406322 /lib64/libutil-2.12.so
rserver   9597 rstudio-server  mem       REG                8,1     65928     391959 /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
rserver   9597 rstudio-server    0u      CHR                1,3       0t0       3643 /dev/null
rserver   9597 rstudio-server    1u      CHR                1,3       0t0       3643 /dev/null
rserver   9597 rstudio-server    2u      CHR                1,3       0t0       3643 /dev/null
rserver   9597 rstudio-server    3r     FIFO                0,8       0t0      37905 pipe
rserver   9597 rstudio-server    4w     FIFO                0,8       0t0      37905 pipe
rserver   9597 rstudio-server    5u      REG                0,9         0       3641 anon_inode
rserver   9597 rstudio-server    6u     IPv4              37907       0t0        TCP *:msgsrvr (LISTEN)
```

Comment: check firewall settings. try telneting to 8787 port if its not connectable. also verify netstat -a |grep 8787 to see if port is listening

Comment: sorry I did not realize you were connecting from the same machine. Check netstat -a |grep 8787 and particular port is in listening state.

Comment: i tried that there was no output.. still got same error 'Unable to connect to service'

Comment: if netstat -a |grep 8787 does not return anything.. that means Rstudio server is not running properly. it should return below line netstat -a |grep 8787
tcp        0      0 *:8787                  *:*                     LISTEN

Comment: when i start localhost:8787, i get the username and pwd page.. what should i do in this case.. do i need to uninstall and reinstall again rstudio will that work..

Comment: I faced the same issue, I dont recollect what exactly I did to resolve it, wait for some expert to come and help. In mean time U can check logs to pin point exact error. /var/log/user.log (Messages related to RStudio will be prefixed with either rserver or rsession).

Comment: In username and pwd page, You should enter Linux username and password (I believe you are aware of this, just to double confirm :)

Comment: also try rebooting your server, it might help

Comment: yes did that.. i have created new user to login into rstudio... i was working earlier.. i uninstalled complete r and rsudio as i was getting error with rjava and rhdfs... after lots of trying i was able to install everything except rstudio..

Comment: basically issue is due to permissions. sudo adduser to create new user(useradd has few issues with Rstudio). After installation restart the server. Im nt sure what exactly is the issue, few pointers for you to check.

Comment: yes I have added the user and restart server.. it used to work previously.. no idea what happened now... :(

Comment: check what is the error in /var/log/user.log and post it here

Comment: file is empty, no entry in that.. just wanted check if this is the path for user.log..

Comment: Recently, the Rstudio official website recommend you look at 
log files in these location::::

For Debian and ubuntu ==> /var/log/syslog ::::
RedHat and CentOS ==> /var/log/messages

Answer (score 24):

When you login the `rserver` process handles your authentication, and then fires up an `rsession` process, which is the session you will use.  The problem occurs when the `rsession` process terminates due to an error.

If you have administrator privileges, you can debug the error by tracing the `rserver` process and looking at the problem that caused `rsession` to exit.
Here is how to do it.

First find the `rserver` process-id.

```
ps auxw | grep studio
rstudio-server       7035  0.0  0.0 362488  4480 ?        Ssl  16:37   0:01 /usr/local/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver
```

Note the second number that appears on the output of a row containing the string `rstudio-server/bin/rserver`.  In the case above the process-id is 7035.

Then trace `rserver` sending the output to a file.  The number after `-p` should be the `rserver` process-id.  The funky `-e` option is used to cut-down noise from Java's thread management.

```
sudo strace -f -e 'trace=!clock_gettime,gettimeofday,futex,timerfd_settime,epoll_wait,epoll_ctl' -p 7035 -o trace.txt
```

Login and wait for the error message to appear.

Stop the tracing by pressing `ctrl-c`.

Open the file with your favourite editor, and search for the string `exit_group`.

The lines above it are likely to indicate the error in `rsession`.  In my case it was a symbolic link from `.rstudio` to a missing directory.

```
7529  mkdir("/home/dds/.rstudio", 0777) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
7529  stat("/home/dds/.rstudio", 0x7ffff37419b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
7529  write(2, "07 Feb 2015 16:46:53 [rsession-d"..., 395) = 395
7529  sendto(3, "<11>Feb  7 16:46:53 rsession-dds"..., 398, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 398
7529  exit_group(1)
```

Comment: very, very helpful - in my case /tmp/rstudio-rsession was owned by root and not writable

Comment: Very helpful ! I have an issue with network drives set as working directory in some projects.
Found the active session and was able to delete the session folder :  `rm -r /home/user/.local/share/rstudio/sessions/active/session-9cc8d010 `

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue while installing Rstudio server on Ubuntu. After following the instructions, I found that I needed to create a home directory folder for each user logging into the Rstudio browser session.

```
12414 mkdir("/home/chamal", 0777)       = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
12414 sendto(3, "<11>Jun 24 08:43:48 rsession-cha"..., 375, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 375
12414 exit_group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A popup titled "RStudio Initialization Error" appears with message "Unable to connect to service". To fix it, I tried appending the following to `/etc/profile` so that Revolution R is picked up by RStudio Server Pro sessions for every user:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/RRO/RRO-8.0.3/R-3.1.3/lib64/R/lib:/usr/local/lib64.`