# Rstudio-server unable to connect to service and locale error

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am having issues connecting to a rstudio server I just installed.  Can you please let me know if you know how to solve this?  Thanks!

I just installed Rstudio server 0.99.485 64-bit on Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy) and am getting this error below:

The error in /var/log/syslog says:

> ERROR Unexpected exception: locale::facet::Screateclocale name not valid;
>
> LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:3166

The symptom is that the web UI says it's "unable to connect to service"

I have followed everything mentioned on [this post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200646688-RStudio-Server-Unable-To-Connect-To-Service), but it doesn't seem to work.

When I trace the rstudio-server process using `sudo strace -f -e 'trace=!clockgettime,gettimeofday,futex,timerfdsettime,epollwait,epollctl' -p 10208 -o trace.txt`, I am seeing this in the `trace.txt` ( below is what I used to log in:

> 10226 connect(10, {safamily=AFLOCAL, sunpath="/tmp/rstudio-rsession/"}, 28) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

I've tried logged in using an invalid id to confirm that pam authentication is working fine

Also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665599/unable-to-start-rstudio-in-centos-getting-error-unable-to-connect-to-service) and made sure there exists `/home/<USERID>` but still the problem is there.