# Rstudio server on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, RStudio initialization error: unable to connect to service

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04, rstudio-server

I have successfully installed Rstudio server (open source) on VM located on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS in the institute cluster. I can access the URL on port 8787. But when I try to sign in to Rstudio using my username and password, it processes for few seconds and then shows the following:

```
RStudio initialization error: unable to connect to service
```

I did not get any error when I ran command `sudo rstudio-server verify-installation`. But when I checked `/var/log/syslog` which shows the following:

```
ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied) [path=/home/biology/.rstudio, target-dir=]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::FilePath::createDirectory(const string&) const /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/FilePath.cpp:826; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:3303
```

PS: R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31); rstudio-server-1.0.136-amd64.deb

Suggestions please.

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried solutions mentioned here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665599/unable-to-start-rstudio-in-centos-getting-error-unable-to-connect-to-service) and here [link] (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204778537-Rstudio-0-99-467-Permission-denied-error-Ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-?page=1#community_comment_115001207127) but not successful so far.

Comment: I created `.rstudio` directory manually and now I am getting following error: `RStudio initialization error: error occur during transmission`

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution for this. I was already having the root access and I proceeded as follows:

```
1) mkdir /home/biology/.rstudio  
2) mkdir /home/biology/.rstudio/graphics-r3  
3) sudo chown -R biology:my_group .rstudio
```

and it worked :)

Comment: bless you, hero.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as @gbioinfo (R version 3.4.2; rstudio-server-1.1.383-amd64.deb; ubuntu 16.04) and had to run the first two commands as `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely Permission for the home directory of the system user that you are trying to use to login to rstudio. 
lets assume that the username is "rstudio_user". simply make sure that you have a home directory created for this user and this user has full permissions or ownership permission to access the directory.

At least for my experience, when I created the username, the username didn't have a home directory. so simply follow the below

```
sudo mkdir /home/rstudio_user
sudo chown -R rstudio_user rstudio_user
```